# In JavaScript, why is +[1.5] considered numeric?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, loose-typing

I've been doing JavaScript a *long* time, but just noticed something I've never seen before.  Consider:

```
> +[1.5]
1.5
```

Why does this happen?  Is this a special rule to interpret arrays as numerical or is it an accident of spec alchemy?

Note also that:

```
> +[1,0]
NaN
```

This makes sense to me, of course, but I would have expected that `+[1]` is also NaN because, well, it's not a number.  Or is it somehow classified as a number?

Then there are these cases, which lead me to believe we're traveling through a type coercion wormhole (array ==> string, string ==> number):

```
> [2] + [4]
"24"
> + [2] + [4]
"24"
> (+[2]) + (+[4])
6
> +[2] + [4,5]
"24,5"
> // which, incidentally, looks like a european-formatted number, but I see
> // that that's just an accident (still another possibility for confusion)
```

Is any of this intentional?

Comment: "intentional" as "by the spec"? Yes.

Comment: Look up coercion to string, coercion to number.

Comment: Off the top of my head I'd think the array is converted to a string representation and that string representation interpreted as number. `[1.5]` → `'1.5'` → `1.5`. The string representation of `[1,0]` is `'1,0'`, which is not numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unary `+` operator internally uses the ToNumber abstract operation.

So the unary operator when applies to an object it applies `toString()` **(abstract operation ToPrimitive)** first and then applies **ToNumber abstract operation**, So basically `+` when applied to array of single number it converts it to the number itself.

If it is applied to `[4,5]` then toString will return `4,5` which inturn when applied a ToNumber abstract operation returns NaN.

```
// Trying to concatenate two string as [] coerce to strings = 24
[2] + [4]
// Converting 2 and 4 to number and then adding = 6   
(+[2]) + (+[4])
// Converting 2 to number and 4,5 will be coerced to string = 24,5
+[2] + [4,5]
```

Comment: Why the special case for "array of single number"? Where is that specified?

Comment: @deceze see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Before apply unary `+` to array it converts to String using `toString` and then try to convert it to Number.

so

```
+[1.5]
```

act as

```
+([1.5].toString())
```

therefore

```
+[1,0]
```

converts [1,0] (array that consist from two elements) to string `1,5` and then tries convert it to number

```
+[1,0] => +"1,0" => NaN
```

in this example:

```
+[2] + [4,5] => +"2" + "4,5" => 2 + "4,5" => "24,5"
```